# How can i display a QR Code-image in a Cognos Report?

Tags: report, ibm-cloud, qr-code, cognos

I have a QR Code generator running on a server, what i want is embed the URL to the COgnos report that displays that URL in a column. Currently i adding that URL in to the Report expression,
Note: Url returns the QR code image as a JPG format.
TIA, Any help will be highly appreciated!

i have also tried having that URL as text source but nothing seem to work.

Comment: "Url returns the QR code image as a JPG format."  I'm confused.  Isn't that the goal?  And who is Tia and what does she have to do with the question?

Comment: Is the question really "How can I display an image in a Cognos report?"  What have you tried.  Does the documentation found by clicking once on the "Learn" button in the top right and entering the word "image" in the search bar not get you there?  What else have you tried?